# Why doesn't Java's Thread.join() wait for all threads to die in this code?

Tags: java, multithreading

I loop through my array of threads and start each. Then in a second loop I call thread.join() for each thread expecting it to wait for all threads to die and then the main thread resuming execution but this isn't what happens. The threads do not seem to join but continue to execute past the join.

I've tried individually calling the join method for each thread but that doesn't work. I found a work around by using Count Down Latch and it gives me the result I want and expect but I am looking to use the built in thread methods.

```
for (UserThread thread : threadArray)
{
    UserThread newThread = new UserThread();
    thread = newThread;
    thread.start();
}
for (UserThread thread : threadArray)
{
    thread.join();
}
```

This is what I see when I use thread.join().

```
Before
data.array[0] = 0
data.array[1] = 1
```

---

```
Creating Thread_0 with threadInt 0
Starting Thread_0
Creating Thread_1 with threadInt 1
Starting Thread_1
Running Thread_0
```

---

```
Thread: Thread_0 adding 5 to threadInt 
After
data.array[0] = 5
Thread Thread_0 exiting.
Running Thread_1
data.array[1] = 1
Thread: Thread_1 adding 5 to threadInt 
Thread Thread_1 exiting.
```

This is what I expect to see using thread.join and see when I use Count Down Latch.

```
Before
data.array[0] = 0
data.array[1] = 1
```

---

```
Creating Thread_0 with threadInt 0
Starting Thread_0
Creating Thread_1 with threadInt 1
Starting Thread_1
Running Thread_0
Thread: Thread_0 adding 5 to threadInt 
Running Thread_1
Thread: Thread_1 adding 5 to threadInt 
Thread Thread_0 exiting.
```

---

```
After
Thread Thread_1 exiting.
data.array[0] = 5
data.array[1] = 6
```

Comment: You're asking why your code produces certain output, but you haven't showed us the code the produces the output.  What does your `UserThread` class look like?

Comment: Possibly relevant: The first `for` loop in your example appears to iterate over an array of `UserThread` instances, but it _completely ignores_ the instances from the array.  It creates _new_ `UserThread` objects, it starts each one, then it forgets them.  The `UserThread` objects that are `join()ed` by the second loop are not the same thread objects that were started by the first loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was as Solomon Slow pointed out, I was creating a new thread then forgetting about it. That error was introduced when attempting to solve an unrelated issue was was left in. The code below gives me the same result (expected) as Count Down Latch.

```
    for (UserThread thread : threadArray)
    {
        thread = new UserThread();
        thread.start();
    }

    for (UserThread thread : threadArray)
    {
        if (thread != null)
            thread.join();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as can see the issue here is related to thread variable reference assignment. 
You're trying to assign to variable `thread`, it's the iteration variable. This assignment won't change the array because `thread` variable is a copy of reference to the current array element. If you want to initialize correctly you should do it in common loop with counter:

```
for (int i = 0; i < threadArray.length; ++i) {
    UserThread newThread = new UserThread();
    threadArray[i] = newThread;
    threadArray[i].start();
}
```

It seems like you will be able to join your threads afterwards.